# Is $\infty + (\infty/\infty)$ indeterminate?

Tags: limits, infinity, indeterminate-forms

I know $ (\infty/\infty)$ is indeterminate, but it can't be less than $0$.

So can you assume $\infty + (\infty/\infty)$  is determinate because $\infty + n$ where $n\ge 0$ is still $\infty$ ?

---

The equation this question is based off of is $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n \log n + n}{\log n}.$$

---

This is in the context of big O notation. Would this be form be valid to use to determine the numerator's function is big Omega of the denominator? Or should l'hopitals rule be used to find a determinate and defined limit?

Comment: If you are able to define your terms, the expression may be determinate. You haven't said what you mean by $\infty$, so at the moment your expression is undefined.

Comment: The original equation is lim n->∞ (nlogn +n)/ logn, which simplifies to n+n/logn, and then plugging in gives ∞+(∞/∞)

Comment: The expression $\infty + (\infty/\infty)$ is nonsense.  Presumably, what you are trying to compute is something like $$\lim_{x\to a} \left[ f(x) + \frac{g(x)}{h(x)} \right], $$ where $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \lim_{x\to a} g(x) = \lim_{x\to a} h(x). $$  That being said, since $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)/h(x)$ is assumed to be nonnegative, it follows that the limit of interest is infinite (this would not be the case if it were possible for $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)/h(x)$ could be negative infinity).

Comment: That being said, I wouldn't think about the limit in the way in which you have.  Instead: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n\log(n) + n}{\log(n)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} n\frac{\log(n) + 1}{\log(n)} \ge \lim_{n\to\infty} n \frac{\log(n)}{\log(n)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} n = +\infty. $$

Comment: Sorry I keep messing up my response. I'm going to redo it.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I like you're later answer, but could I instead change it to this: lim→∞(log()+n)/log(n) =  lim→∞log()/log(n)  +lim→∞1/log() = *plugging in* =∞+0=∞. Also sorry I'm not quite sure how to format it like you did.

Comment: Another approach is $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln n}\right)$.

Comment: @J.G. I think the n outside the parenthesis should be n/logn. Maybe I'm wrong and if so can you show how you got to your approach?

Comment: @BenStoller You are wrong. I just factorised your original numerator, then divided out $\ln n$ in the parentheses.

Comment: @J.G. Oh yea you're right. My mistake.

Comment: Actually, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n\log(n)+n)/\log(n) \neq \lim_{n\to\infty} n\log(n)/\log(n) +\lim_{n\to\infty}1/\log(n)$. In order to get equality, you need to replace the $1$ with $n$, and then you end up with $\infty+\infty.$

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This is a very interesting question... I believe you are correct. Below is a proof.

1. Let $lim_{x \rightarrow a}[f(x)/g(x)]$ be some arbitrary indeterminate function such that $lim_{x \rightarrow a}[f(x)/g(x)]=\infty/\infty$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $a$ is a finite real number.
2. Also let $lim_{x \rightarrow b}[h(x)]=\infty$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $b$ is a finite real number.
3. As $x\rightarrow a$, we know that $f$ and $g$ either (i) grow at the same rate, (ii.) $f$ grows faster than $g$, or (iii.) $g$ grows faster than $f$.

Case i.

1. If $f$ and $g$ grow at the same rate, then $lim_{x \rightarrow a}[f(x)/g(x)]=L$ where $L\in \mathbb{R}$.
2. Then, $lim_{x \rightarrow b}[h(x)]+lim_{x \rightarrow a}[f(x)/g(x)]=\infty+L=\infty$.

Case ii.

1. If $f$ grows faster than $g$, then $lim_{x \rightarrow a}[f(x)/g(x)]=\infty$.
2. Then, $lim_{x \rightarrow b}[h(x)]+lim_{x \rightarrow a}[f(x)/g(x)]=\infty+\infty=\infty$.

Case iii.

1. If $g$ grows faster than $f$, then $lim_{x \rightarrow a}[f(x)/g(x)]=0$.
2. Then, $lim_{x \rightarrow b}[h(x)]+lim_{x \rightarrow a}[f(x)/g(x)]=\infty+0=\infty$.

Hence, in any case, $lim_{x \rightarrow b}[h(x)]+lim_{x \rightarrow a}[f(x)/g(x)]=\infty+(\infty/\infty)=\infty$

In this proof we are using limits to make sense of your statement, but I don't think you NEED limits to make sense of the statement. $\infty$ is simply a quantity increasing without limit... Some folks are saying $\infty/\infty$ is undefined; this is not true. It is indeterminate because the answer EXISTS, only it cannot be determined in the current form. By adding $\infty$ to the expression you obtain another expression that is suddenly in determinate form.

Comment: This is not a proof.  The rough idea is correct but there are numerous errors in your argument; for instance, it is not correct to write $lim_{x \rightarrow a}[f(x)/g(x)]=\infty/\infty$, and your three cases do not cover all possibilities (the limit could simply not exist).

Comment: This "proof" could use a bit more rigor.

Comment: Try using built in LaTeX functions like \lim

Comment: Communicating that a proof could use more "rigor" without a suggestion is not constructive, N. Bar

Comment: Eric, admittedly line 1 can be developed a bit better, but it is in fact fine to write, and the proof does cover all possibilities. Technically, an infinite limit is a limit that does not exist, so my proof does include such a case. I think what you mean is that there could be a limit that does not exist in addition to the infinite limit. The assumption in line 1 omits this possibility.

Comment: You know what is _less_ constructive than communicating that a proof could use more "rigor" without a suggestion? Letting stand a proof full of nonsensical notation and logical holes. Here's one example you apparently didn't think about: $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = (2x + x\sin(x)).$ Then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/g(x)$ does not fit any of your three cases, because contrary to your assertion that $\infty/\infty$ "exists", in this case the limit does not exist; it is not even infinite.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the fact that if $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)= \infty$ and $\liminf\limits_{x\to c}g(x)\ge 0$, then eventually $f(x)+g(x)\ge f(x)-1\to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a great question! $\frac{\infty}{\infty} + \infty$ is not an *indeterminate form*, and usually it's considered *undefined*. However, it would be reasonable to consider it to be *defined* and equal to $\infty$; this is an alternate definition that is perfectly reasonable.

---

**Question 1. Is $\frac{\infty}{\infty} + \infty$ an *indeterminate form?***

**Answer: No.** The expression $\frac{\infty}{\infty} + \infty$ is not an *indeterminate form,* because the words "indeterminate form" have a technical meaning, and that specifically means an expression which is one of the following:

$$\frac 00,~ \frac{\infty}{\infty},~ 0\times\infty,~ 1^\infty,~ \infty-\infty,~ 0^0 \text{ and } \infty^0.$$

Now, notice that $\frac{\infty}{\infty} + \infty$ is not one of the values on this list. Therefore, it's not an indeterminate form.

---

**Question 2. Is $\frac{\infty}{\infty} + \infty$ *defined?***

**Answer: Not according to the standard definition.** Usually, we would say that an *undefined* value plus any other value (or times any other value, or multiplied by any other value, etc.) is just undefined. That is, if any part of an expression is undefined, the whole thing is undefined. Consider these examples:

$$
1 + \frac{0}{0} = \textbf{undefined} \quad \text{(subexpression } \frac{0}{0} \text{ is undefined so the expression is undefined})
$$
$$
0 \cdot \left(\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin x \right) = \textbf{undefined} \quad \text{(subexpression } \lim_{x \to \infty} \sin x \text{ is undefined so the expression is undefined})
$$
$$
\frac{\infty}{\infty} + \infty = \textbf{undefined} \quad \text{(subexpression } \frac{\infty}{\infty} \text{ is undefined so the expression is undefined})
$$

---

**Question 3. OK, but is there some alternate definition that we can use so that $\frac{\infty}{\infty} + \infty = \infty$?**

**Answer: Yes!**
There is something called a [multivalued function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function) that is often used in math, particularly in a branch of math called complex analysis. A "multivalued function" is where we assign the value of an expression to be *all possible values that make sense* instead of just one value. So in the multivalued-function world, we would say that
$$
\frac{0}{0} = \text{all real numbers and $\infty$ and $-\infty$}
$$
That is, we have said that the value of dividing $0$ by $0$ is not just one value, but *all values* because any value makes sense as the answer.

Using multi-valued functions, we would then say that
$$
\frac{\infty}{\infty} = \text{ all nonnegative real numbers and } \infty,
$$
because any nonnegative answer makes sense. Then, we would have that
$$
\frac{\infty}{\infty} + \infty = \infty,
$$
because if you add any nonnegative number to $\infty$, you get $\infty$.

This is an **alternate, nonstandard** definition, so it's important to know that your textbook or math teacher might not agree; but it's a perfectly valid alternate semantics, and it's useful in some areas of math.

Comment: An "indeterminate form" is a limit which, when we attempt to use the basic limit laws (essentially, the continuity of addition, multiplication, exponentiation; and the composition of continuous functions), gives an expression which does not have a unique value, such as $\infty/\infty$ or $1^{\infty}$.  An indeterminate form is *not* just a limit which simplifies to one of the forms on your list.  For example, $$ \frac{\infty}{\infty} - \infty $$ is not on your list, but is indeterminate.  Hence I think that your "**Answer 1**" is misleading.

Comment: I should have mentioned this in the post but this is in the context of big O notation. Would this be form be valid to use to determine the numerator's function is big Omega of the denominator? Or should l'hopitals rule be used to find a determinate and defined limit?

Comment: Regarding "**Answer 2**", I think that there is a confusing mix of things which are correct and incorrect.  The term $\infty/\infty$ is not defined.  But the limits in question are not equal to $\infty/\infty$.  They are equal to whatever they are equal to, but may take the "form" $\infty/\infty$ when analyzed naively.  When a limit takes the form $\infty + \infty/\infty$, this suggests that naive analysis is inappropriate.  This does not imply that the limit is undefined.

Comment: @XanderHenderson On question 1, the definition I am familiar with is: "An indeterminate form is an expression involving two functions whose limit cannot be determined solely from the limits of the individual functions." (see [brilliant](https://brilliant.org/wiki/indeterminate-forms/)). So an indeterminate form is a limit expression of the form $\lim \text{op}(f(x), g(x))$, such that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both have a limit, but $op$ is not defined on the resulting arguments.

Comment: Finally, I think that the introduction of "multivalued functions" in "**Answer 3**" is irrelevant, and doesn't actually explain anything.  We are discussing limits in $\mathbb{R}$, not functions on a Riemann surface.

Comment: @6005 The definition you give in your comment is *not* the definition you gave in your answer.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks for your comments. On answer 2: This has nothing to do with limits, I am talkingabout algebra in $\mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty, \infty\}$. $\infty - \infty$ is undefined in the algebraic sense in the same way as $\frac{0}{0}$ is undefined. On answer 3: what of functions on a Riemann surface? I'm bringing it up because I thought the OP might like to know that the definition that they suggested is a reasonable one, even though it's not correct. I also though the OP might like to know that it's not just a reasonable definition, but it's actually used in complex analysis.

Comment: @XanderHenderson True, they differ although not fundamentally; the latter definition implies the former if we restrict to the standard operations (addition, multiplication, division, and exponentiation).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98964/discussion-between-xander-henderson-and-6005).

Comment: The question is not literally about the meaning of $\infty+\infty/\infty$.  It is about what you can say about a limit which has this form.  So, the only part of this answer that is really relevant to the question is the first part, which as Xander pointed out is misleading if not wrong.  (The third part is also indirectly relevant in that the multivalued operations you talk about are closely related to how limits can behave, but this requires more explanation to really address the question.)

Comment: @EricWofsey When I answered the question there was no limit expression. Just the algebraic expression $\frac{\infty}{\infty} + \infty$.

Comment: I understand you may still object to the first part of the answer, that I define "indeterminate form" in a rather dumb way (the term itself is dumb, isn't it?). But I hope that puts the rest of the answer in context.

Comment: The original version of the question was already about limits--that's what it means to ask whether an expression like this is "indeterminate" (and if there was any doubt, the tags on the question definitely made the intended meaning clear).

Comment: @EricWofsey Whenever I post things about arithmetic on $\infty$, I get downvotes. I think there is this dogmatic view that $\infty$ is never a number and we should always think of it as a limit, and any expression involving $\infty$ is not a first-class citizen but really means you are trying to compute some limit.

OK, the downvotes are fair, because nothing I said helps OP to evaluate whatever limit they were doing. But I find it fun to think about the semantics of expressions with infinity allowed as a first-class citizen, and I don't find it fun to evaluate basic limits.

Comment: I don't disagree with you about $\infty$.  If the question were about how to make sense of the expression $\infty+\infty/\infty$ then I would have upvoted, but this question is specifically about limits.

Comment: @EricWofsey That makes perfect sense, I'm glad we have come to a mutual understanding!

Comment: I'm hoping this gets to -3 so I can finally get the "Peer Pressure" badge

Answer (score 1):

So if we know that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} f(n) = +\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} h(n) = +\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} g(n) = +\infty$, can we assure that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(f(n) + \frac {h(n)}{g(n)} = \infty$?

Yes.

For any $M$ there is an $N_1$ so that $n > N$ implies $f(n) > M$.  And for $0$ there is an $N_2$ so that $n>N_2$ implies  that $h(n) > 0$  (a bit of overkill for $h(n) \to \infty$ ... but what the heck...) and an $N_2$ so that $n > N_3$ implies that $g(n) > 0$.

So there is an $N \ge \max(N_1,N_2,N_3)$ so that if $n > N$ then $f(n) > M$ and $\frac {h(n)}{g(n)} > 0$ so $f(n) +\frac {h(n)}{g(n)} > f(n) > M$.

Thus $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(f(n) + \frac {h(n)}{g(n)} = \infty$.

For you example $\lim \frac {n\log n+n}{\log n} =\lim n(1+ \frac 1{\log n})$

We know $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\log n=\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\log (1+\frac 1{\log n}) = 1$.

Does that mean $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\log n(1+ \frac 1{\log n}) =\infty$?

Yes.  For every $M$  there is an $N_1$ so that if $n > N_1$ then $n > M$ and there is an $N_2$ so that if $n >N_2$ then $\frac 1{\log n} < \frac 1M$ so if $n > \max (N_1,N_2)$ we have $n(1+ \frac 1{\log n}) >M(1+\frac 1M)>M$.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of limits of real numbers, $\infty+\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ is not an indeterminate form but can instead be said to be "equal to $\infty$".  To be precise, what this means is the following:

> Suppose $(a_n)$, $(b_n)$, and $(c_n)$ are sequences of real numbers such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\infty,\  \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=\infty, \text{ and } \lim_{n\to\infty} c_n=\infty.$$ Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(a_n+\frac{b_n}{c_n}\right)=\infty.$$

The reasoning you suggest is the rough intuitive idea behind why this should be true, but it is not a rigorous proof since we are not actually literally adding $\infty+\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ but are instead taking a certain limit.  To prove it rigorously, fix $M\in\mathbb{R}$ and choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n>M$ and $b_n,c_n>0$ for all $n>N$ (we can do this since the three sequences go to $\infty$ and so are eventually greater than any fixed real number).  Then for any $n>N$, $$a_n+\frac{b_n}{c_n}>a_n>M.$$  That is, $a_n+\frac{b_n}{c_n}$ is eventually greater than any fixed real number, so its limit is $\infty$.